# Convert timestamps in JSON string with Bash commands

Tags: json, bash, datetime, timestamp, format

I have the following string as below:

```
{
  "name": {
    "value": "Demo"
  },
  "activity": {
    "value": "CLOSED",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.534+0000"
  },
  "state": {
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.570+0000"
  },
  "lastErrorCode": {
    "value": "NO_MESSAGE",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.570+0000"
  }
}
```

How can I convert all timestamps in that string to another format (Timezone)? Example like (on cmd line):

```
echo '2020-11-19T10:58:17.534+0000' | xargs date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d
```

results in:

```
2020-11-19 11:58:17
```

Comment: seems to work partly. If i omit the last piped command i do get the converted dates. Otherwise it throughs: jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "activity"

Comment: With your sample it works fine here, I must have copied the wrong command. `jq -r '(.activity, .state, .lastErrorCode) .timestamp' file | date -f - '+"%F %T"' | jq 'reduce path((.activity, .state, .lastErrorCode) .timestamp) as $p (.; setpath($p; input))' file -`.

Comment: awesome ! works for me now as well with file operation. Did try this with direct string manipulation - guess this is where my error came from. Any idea how to get that running with string manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

That string of yours is actually a JSON(-string). Please use a tool that supports JSON and can do dateTime-conversions, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

First of all, the value of the `timestamp`-keys is not a valid dateTime. You'd have to change the timezone property `0000` to `00:00` to make it a valid one:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '
  for $x in $json//timestamp return
  dateTime(replace($x,"0000","00:00"))
'
2020-11-19T10:58:17.534Z
2020-11-19T10:58:17.57Z
2020-11-19T10:58:17.57Z
```

Then to change the timezone to `+01:00` use [`adjust-dateTime-to-timezone()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-adjust-dateTime-to-timezone):

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '
  for $x in $json//timestamp return
  adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(
    dateTime(replace($x,"0000","00:00")),
    duration("PT1H")
  )
'
2020-11-19T11:58:17.534+01:00
2020-11-19T11:58:17.57+01:00
2020-11-19T11:58:17.57+01:00
```

*(You can remove `duration("PT1H")` if your timezone already is `+01:00`)*

Finally to customize your output use [`format-dateTime()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-format-dateTime):

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '
  for $x in $json//timestamp return
  format-dateTime(
    adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(
      dateTime(replace($x,"0000","00:00")),
      duration("PT1H")
    ),
    "[Y]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]"
  )
'
2020-11-19 11:58:17
2020-11-19 11:58:17
2020-11-19 11:58:17
```

---

If instead you want to update the JSON with these customized dateTimes... that can be done, but requires a more advanced recursive function:

```
$ xidel -s input.json --xquery '
  declare function local:change-timestamp($a){
    if (exists($a)) then
      if ($a instance of map(*)) then
        map:merge(
          map:keys($a) ! map{
            .:if (.="timestamp") then
              format-dateTime(
                adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(
                  dateTime(replace($a(.),"0000","00:00")),
                  duration("PT1H")
                ),
                "[Y]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]"
              )
            else
              local:change-timestamp($a(.))
          }
        )
      else
        $a
    else
      ()
  };
  local:change-timestamp($json)
'
{
  "name": {
    "value": "Demo"
  },
  "activity": {
    "value": "CLOSED",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 11:58:17"
  },
  "state": {
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 11:58:17"
  },
  "lastErrorCode": {
    "value": "NO_MESSAGE",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 11:58:17"
  }
}
```

Also check the [`xidel` playground](https://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22Demo%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22activity%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22CLOSED%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%222020-11-19T10%3A58%3A17.534%2B0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22state%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22OK%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%222020-11-19T10%3A58%3A17.570%2B0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22lastErrorCode%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22NO_MESSAGE%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%222020-11-19T10%3A58%3A17.570%2B0000%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&extract=declare%20function%20local%3Achange-timestamp(%24a)%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(exists(%24a))%20then%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%24a%20instance%20of%20map(*))%20then%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20map%3Amerge(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%3Akeys(%24a)%20!%20map%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%3Aif%20(.%3D%22timestamp%22)%20then%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format-dateTime(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dateTime(replace(%24a(.)%2C%220000%22%2C%2200%3A00%22))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration(%22PT1H%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5BY%5D-%5BM01%5D-%5BD01%5D%20%5BH01%5D%3A%5Bm01%5D%3A%5Bs01%5D%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20local%3Achange-timestamp(%24a(.))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24a%0D%0A%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20%24x%20in%20%24json%2F%2Ftimestamp%20return%20dateTime(replace(%24x%2C%220000%22%2C%2200%3A00%22))%2C%22%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20%24x%20in%20%24json%2F%2Ftimestamp%20return%0D%0Aadjust-dateTime-to-timezone(%0D%0A%20%20dateTime(replace(%24x%2C%220000%22%2C%2200%3A00%22))%2C%0D%0A%20%20duration(%22PT1H%22)%0D%0A)%2C%22%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20%24x%20in%20%24json%2F%2Ftimestamp%20return%0D%0Aformat-dateTime(%0D%0A%20%20adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dateTime(replace(%24x%2C%220000%22%2C%2200%3A00%22))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20duration(%22PT1H%22)%0D%0A%20%20)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22%5BY%5D-%5BM01%5D-%5BD01%5D%20%5BH01%5D%3A%5Bm01%5D%3A%5Bs01%5D%22%0D%0A)%2C%22%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0Alocal%3Achange-timestamp(%24json)&extract-kind=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using regex. Something like this:

```
str='{
  "name": {
    "value": "Demo"
  },
  "activity": {
    "value": "CLOSED",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.534+0000"
  },
  "state": {
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.570+0000"
  },
  "lastErrorCode": {
    "value": "NO_MESSAGE",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19T10:58:17.570+0000"
  }
}'

re='(.*?-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)T([0-9:]+)(\.[0-9+]+)(.*)'
while [[ $str =~ $re ]]; do
  str="${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
done
echo "$str"
```

Returns:

```
{
  "name": {
    "value": "Demo"
  },
  "activity": {
    "value": "CLOSED",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 10:58:17"
  },
  "state": {
    "value": "OK",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 10:58:17"
  },
  "lastErrorCode": {
    "value": "NO_MESSAGE",
    "timestamp": "2020-11-19 10:58:17"
  }
}
```

Comment: Regex cannot parse JSON or any markup language reliably.

Comment: Guess that points towards the right direction - so thanks for that. However a date processing does not take place because 2020-11-19T10:58:17.534+0000 is 2020-11-19 11:58:17 in my Timezone (and not 2020-11-19 10:58:17). Not sure how to incorporate a 'date -d' in there.